# Undefined offset 0 - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent

Eu tenho uma listagem de usuários, cada usuário tem sua 'role' (papel/função dentro do sistema, como 'user' e 'admin') e essa role tem que ser mostrada na tela de listagem de usuários, que eu fiz utilizando o bloco de código abaixo.

```
@foreach ($users as $key => $user)
 <tr class="list-users">
  <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
  <td>{{ $user->roles[0]->name }}</td>
 </tr>
@endforeach
```

O erro ocorre com esta linha `<td>{{ $user->roles[0]->name }}</td>`, indicando que 'roles' não tem o índice '0', mas quando eu faço um dump `{{ dd($user->roles[0]->name) }}`, ele me retorna a variável normalmente ( uma string com o nome da 'role' do usuário).

Se eu tento acessar utilizando a 'role' utilizando `{{ $user->roles()->first()->name }}` o caso é similar. Com o `dd()` funciona normalmente, mas no `@foreach` da listagem ocorre um erro. A única diferença é o tipo de erro retornado: `'Trying to get property 'name' of non-object '`.

O que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: Como você está passando o $users para a página?

Comment: Sim. @sant0will

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As vezes, um usuário pode não ter uma `role` definida, e mesmo que pela pergunta eu entenda que todo usuário possui uma `role`, as vezes, pode ser o caso de que foi cadastrado sem uma `role`.

Eu sugeriria usar o seguinte código para ter certeza que o usuário possui alguma `role`:

```
{{ is_null($user->roles()->first()) ? 'Sem qualificação' : $user->roles()->first()->name }}
```

---

E uma dica, se não estiver usando a função `with` ao carregar os usuários, eu sugeriria usar para não ter que carregar essas informações na hora de exibir.

Bastaria você colocar a função `with('roles')` ao carregar os usuários, aqui está a documentação, [Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading).

Comment: Exatamente isso, obrigado. o ultimo usuário da listagem não tinha uma 'role' definida pra ele e por isso ocorria o erro. o dd() exibia o dump somente do primeiro registro, que é do administrador e ele tem uma role definida. Por isso no dd() funcionava normalmente, mas na listagem não.